# Calling new Date() inside constructor throws error Maximum call stack size exceeded React Native

Tags: react-native

Here is my constructor. When I run the code it throws the following error in React Native 0.61x.

```
export default class Date extends Component {

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;
  };



constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      title: null,
      day: new Date(),
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props

return(
  <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
    <Header
      navigation={navigation}
      icon='back'/>
      <Title>{i18n.t('create.date_title')}</Title>
  </View>
)
  }
}
```

> Unhandled JS Exception: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

When I comment the code it does not throw the error anymore.

Also, why is StackOverflow so bad at copy pasting code? I am doing something wrong or what cause only a few lines of code get indented as code when I paste them.

Comment: I think you've done it wrong somewhere. Copying the code is a natural copy.

Answer (score 1):

Running these features in the creator can cause a lot of renderings.

You can use `componentDidMount()`

```js
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //defauilt value of the date time
      date: '',
    };
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    var date = new Date()
    that.setState({ date: date });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your declaration `export default class Date extends Component`

You are overwriting `Date` with your own Component. Try renaming your Component.